# How to extractstring between two characters in a column of spark dataframe

Tags: string, pyspark, extract

I am dealing with spark data frame `df` which has two columns `tstamp` and `c_1`. Data type for `c_1` is 'string', and I want to add a new column by extracting string between two characters in that field.

For example: original dataframe `df`

| tstamp | c_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-06-15 10:00:00 | xxx&cd7=H10S10P10&cd21=GA&cd3=6... |
| 2022-06-15 10:10:01 | xz&cd7=H11S11P11&cd21=CA&cd3=5... |

We want to add a new column (same or another dataframe) called `cd_7` and the value will be the string between 'cd7=' and '&cd21' like below:

| tstamp | c_1 | cd_7 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-15 10:00:00 | xxx&cd7=H10S10P10&cd21=GA&cd3=6... | H10S10P10 |
| 2022-06-15 10:10:01 | xz&cd7=H11S11P11&cd21=CA&cd3=5... | H11S11P11 |

How could I write it using Pyspark? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to extract everything between special characters `=` and `&`

```
df.withColumn('x', regexp_extract('c_1', '(?<=[\=]).*(?=[\&])',0)).show()

+-------------------+--------------------+---------+
|             tstamp|                 c_1|        x|
+-------------------+--------------------+---------+
|2022-06-15 10:00:00|xxx&cd7=H10S10P10...|H10S10P10|
|2022-06-15 10:10:01|xz&cd7=H11S11P11&...|H11S11P11|
+-------------------+--------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess original example I provided in the question is not good. The dataframe is a raw file and there are quite a few characters before '&cd=7' and after '&cd=21'. (Just updated the example) And for column 'cd_7' (column x in your script) I'd want value for 'cd7' which is the string between 'cd7=' and '&cd21'. Can I use the same regexp_extract function you provided?

Answer (score 0):

Used an alternative way to get the answer by converting this to a pandas dataframe and do data manipulation, but not ideal if data is large.

`df['cd_7'] = df['c_1'].apply(lambda st: st[st.find("cd7=")+4:st.find("&cd21")])`